# firebase запрос на проверку нескольких полей

Tags: android, запрос, firebase

Никак не приходит прозрение касательно того как сделать правильный запрос.
Структура(схематически):

```
root
{
    autocreatedkey
   {
        user_id1 : true
        user_id2 : true
        mess
        {
            ...
        }
   }
}
```

Необходимо написать такой запрос, который бы из множества записей нашел ту где "user_id1" и "user_id2", такие какие были запрошены(в запросе) и вернул узел "autocreatedkey".  И нет таких двух узлов у которых бы значения "user_id1" и "user_id2" одновременно совпадали. "autocreatedkey" - создан автоматически

Все мои попытки приводят либо к тому что я получаю в итоге узел "root" из-за того что не знаю значения "autocreatedkey", либо что генерится не существующий ключ или вообще к ошибкам.

Спасибо!

---UPDATE---

Мне удалось кое как решить проблему, хотя мне это решение  не нравится(потому что я таки не понял запросы), буду благодарен если кто-то покажет как составлять запросы.

Вот код(отрывок) как я решил вопрос:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase;
DatabaseReference dRef;
Boolean RoomCreated = false;
//...
 mDatabase.child("root").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Iterable<DataSnapshot> iter =  dataSnapshot.getChildren();
                        for (DataSnapshot it : iter)
                        {
                          if(it.hasChild(mUser.getUid()) && //<---"user_id1"
                                  it.hasChild(FUid ))  //<---"user_id2"
                            {
                                dRef = it.getRef();
                                RoomCreated = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Обходите ветку со значениями и записываете их в коллецию. А уж из коллеции легко вытащить любое значение.

```
mDatabase.getSomeReference().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mylisty.clear();
            Map<String, Object> newPost = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : newPost.entrySet()) {
                mainID = entry.getKey();
                Map<String, Object> newPost4 = (Map<String, Object>) entry.getValue();
                    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry2 : newPost4.entrySet()) {
                        Map<Object, Object> properties = (Map<Object, Object>) entry.getValue();
                        strName = properties.get("lowerID1").toString();
                        strCity = properties.get("lowerID2").toString();

                    }
                mylisty.add(new InfoClass(strName,strCity));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```